# Programmatically click a button on a PDF XFA form using itext

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I have a PDF xfa form that I am filling out with iText. I am unable to fill certain fields as they become enabled in the form only after clicking on a certain button within the form. This button actually calls a webservice that returns data. The data is used to fill up other fields which I am not bothered with. But only after clicking this button the fields that I am trying to fill out with XML data become enabled (non read only). I can't change the form.

So I am guessing the only way I can fill out these fields by merging the XML data is by clicking this button. Is there a way I can click this button using Itext and then merge the pdf with the xml data I am sending it?

Comment: I assume the button action is coded as JavaScript. IText does not execute JavaScript. If you only have to deal with that single document, you can try to extract the JavaScript code and try to re-program equivalent java code.

Comment: thanks mkl.. I guessed as much :( Don't think I can re program the document. Its a government form and I am not sure its legal to do so.